# Delphi inheritance and constructor create, override base class create

Tags: class, delphi, inheritance

Lets say I have the following (example) classes:

```
TMyClass1 = class(TThread)
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
end;

TMyClass2 = class(TMyClass1)
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
end;
```

code:

```
constructor TMyClass1.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
end;

constructor TMyClass2.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

How can I prevent that TMyClass2.Create does not call the constructor of TMyClass1, but the class is still created properly?

In the real code, create of TMyClass1 does something which should not happen in TMyClass2.create. The TMyClass1 has a lot of functions and procedures, which I do not want to duplicate for TMyClass2.

Comment: Include a parameter in the TMyClass1 ctor that determines whether or not the optional code executes. Note however that what you described smells like bad class design.

Comment: Thank you, you might be right, the design is bad. The create on TMyClass1 increment a counter, which also now get incremented when TMyClass2 create is called, which should not be. I will try to thin it over and redesign the behavior.

Comment: @Softtouch why not just have TMyClass2 skip incrementing the counter if TMyClass1 already does it?

Comment: It's easy enough to answer your question. But without understanding the underlying problem it's hard to give you good advice on how to solve it. For sure though, what you ask about, skipping over the immediate super class ctor and executing the ctor from the grand parent is a really bad idea.

Comment: If they are so different, why does TClass2 actually inherit from TClass1? Why don't they inherit from one single base class, or (probably even better:) use composition to achieve their goals? Or is it just the counter?

Answer (score -3):

There are much ways to do this. Just for example, you can use more than one constructors:

```
TMyClass1 = class(TThread)
protected
  constructor CreateInternal(CreateSuspended: boolean);
public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
end;

....

constructor TMyClass1.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin
  CreateInternal(CreateSuspended);
  ... do other things which shouldn't be in Class2 ...
end;

constructor TMyClass2.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin
  inherited CreateInternal(CreateSuspended);
  ...
end;
```

But generally it looks like design error. Maybe you should make TMyClass0 = class(TThread), TMyClass1 = class(TMyClass0), TMyClass2 = class(TMyClass0), maybe other, but you description is suspicious.

Comment: Into CreateInternal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. In Delphi constructor have no such magic meaning as in C++ or Java, it's just a synonym for "class function which returns result of NewInstance". Technically it's possible to make a class without constructors at all and use it. So CreateInternal may be constructor, may be not constructor... but I guess that 'something which looks as constructor and works as constructor' should be constructor, not something else.